# What is the fastest and most memory efficient way to align large CSV files?

Tags: csv

I want to stack csv files that correspond to different years in a dataset. I have noticed that some of the headers are completely dealigned across the files and need to figure out a fast way to align them all into one output csv.

```
EX: CSV 1
    a b c d e f g
    1 2 3 4 3 4 5

    CSV 2 
    c d e f g x z
    1 2 3 4 5 6 7
```

I want to be able to align c d e f g data in the output CSV as well as include a b x z as well.

Comment: There are many options. Pandas offers this out of the box ( https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/merging.html ). Consider adding a language or framework tag, otherwise the question may be too broad.

Comment: Consider using AWK

Answer (score 0):

You can do it easily with mlr ([Miller](https://miller.readthedocs.io/)) with two built-in commands

First you have to define the target header (a b c d e f g x z).

Then, you just have to use the con**cat**enate function:

```
$ mlr --opprint --barred --itsv template -f a,b,c,d,e,f,g,x,z then cat file1.tsv file2.tsv

+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
| a | b | c | d | e | f | g | x | z |
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
| 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 3 | 4 | 5 |   |   |
|   |   | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 |
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
```

And for a simpler command that will generate the output in TSV assuming the 2 files are in the same format:

```
$ mlr --tsv template -f a,b,c,d,e,f,g,x,z then cat file1.tsv file2.tsv > output.tsv
```